# Stripe preview invoice without an active subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Can we query Stripe with the subscription_items and a quantity to preview the incoming invoice without an active subscription with the Preview API https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/upcoming?

We tried to set subscription_items to preview an invoice without an active subscription. Its response contains a subscription and subscription_item. But when we query the subscription or subscription_item specifically, it threw an error `Invalid subscription_item`.

Eg, When calling /v1/invoices/upcoming with subscription_items

```
curl --location -g --request GET 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/upcoming?customer=cus_MIjwgFDqhg8uBf&subscription_items[0][price]=price_1LDx6JL3XoZTtiHnl5wAWtkg&subscription_items[0][quantity]=1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxx'
{
    "object": "invoice",
    "lines": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "subscription": "sub_1LeoDVL3XoZTtiHn998jF9zp",
                "subscription_item": "si_MNZM3MetxDd9Gu"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then when we query the subscription or subscription_item with /v1/subscription_items/si_MNZM3MetxDd9Gu, it shows `Invalid subscription_item`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid subscription_item id: si_MNZM3MetxDd9Gu",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are viewing an upcoming invoice, you are simply viewing a preview – the invoice and subscription has not yet been created. So you cannot query the subscription or subscription item in the response from the upcoming invoice API.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming does not require an active Subscription. [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming?lang=node#upcoming_invoice-subscription) is an optional parameter. The Stripe docs mention :

*The identifier of the subscription for which you’d like to retrieve the upcoming invoice. If not provided, but a subscription_items is provided, you will preview creating a subscription with those items....*

The below Node.js example code previews creating a subscription :

```
const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
  customer: 'cus_...',
  subscription_items: [
    {
      price : `price_...`,
      quantity : 2
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: But the response contains an invalid subscription and subscription_item though. We tried this before but we can't query the details of the subscription by the id.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the upcoming invoice actually works. When you are viewing an upcoming invoice, you are simply viewing a preview – the invoice and subscription has not yet been created. So you wouldn't be able to query the subscription or subscription item in the response from the upcoming invoice API. Why do you want to retrieve the subscription or subscription item from the upcoming invoice API?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to be able to display a preview of a price for a new non-stripe user.  It looks like Stripe has a resource called `Quote` that you can use for this purpose, customer ID is optional, i.e.:

```
quote = Stripe::Quote.create({ line_items: [{ price: "gateway_price_id" }] })
```

You can view the documentation for it here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/quotes/create?lang=curl